# Can't install Symfony 2.8

Tags: php, symfony, curl, symfony-2.8

I'm trying to install symfony 2.8 in my local computer, under xampp and Windows 10. According to the official documentation, I have to use:

```
php -r "file_put_contents('symfony', file_get_contents('https://symfony.com/installer'));"
```

but https://symfony.com/installer doesn't exist anymore. So, I found I cand install it using composer, in this way:

```
composer create-project symfony/framework-standard-edition sf8 2.8.x-dev
```

or even in this other way:

```
composer create-project symfony/skeleton symfony2.8
```

But in both cases I get the same error (I'll paste from the second one command)

```
https://repo.packagist.org could not be fully loaded (curl error 35 while downloading https://repo.packagist.org/packages.json: error:1407742E:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version), package information was loaded from the local cache and may be out of date


  [Composer\Downloader\TransportException]
  curl error 35 while downloading https://repo.packagist.org/p2/symfony/skeleton.json: error:1407742E:SSL routines:SS
  L23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:tlsv1 alert protocol version
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Are you using any kind of proxy on your PC?

Comment: Your curl binary may be outdated. It looks like it might not be able to negotiate a secure connection to repo.packagist.org. What does `curl --version` show?

Comment: @drew010 curl 7.55.1 (Windows) libcurl/7.55.1 WinSSL
Release-Date: 2017-11-14, security patched: 2019-11-05

Comment: @amirz98 no, I don't

Comment: Looks like it might be an issue with certificates. If you download the latest [cacert.pem](https://curl.se/ca/cacert.pem) from curl and then try `curl --cacert C:/path/to/cacert.pem https://repo.packagist.org/p2/symfony/skeleton.json` does that work as opposed to just `curl https://repo.packagist.org/p2/symfony/skeleton.json` ?  Either way, since your curl version is a bit outdated, you might want to download the latest version from https://curl.se/windows/ and update what you have now.

Comment: @drew010 if I execute this, I get a JSON with all the packages, but nothing more happens. Is that normal?
curl version is which comes with xampp I just installed (with php 5.4 for compatibility with symfony 2.x)

Comment: @drew010 I updated curl and lauch the command and the error was the same